# Combining numpy arrays to create a value field

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

i have coded so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.special import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *
import csv

## Globale Variablen ## 
# kommen später ins main file, MÜSSEN vor dem import von diesem Modul definiert werden!)
rhof = 1000                          # Dichte Flüssigkeit [kg/m³]
lameu = 11.2*10**9                   # Lamé-Parameter, undrained [GPa]
lame = 8.4*10**9                     # Lamé-Parameter, drained [GPa]
pi                                   # durch Pythonmodul "math" gegeben
alpha = 0.65                         # Biot-Willis-Koeffizient
G = 8.4*10**9                        # Schermodul [GPa]
k = 1.0e-15                          # Permeabilität [m²] bzw. [Darcy] 
eta = 0.001                          # Viskosität des Fluids [Pa*s]

## Berechnung der Parameter ##

# Berechnung der Diffusivität 
kappa = k/eta                       
# Berechnung der Diffusivität 
c = ((kappa*(lameu-lame)*(lame+2*G))/((alpha**2)*(lameu+2*G)))   


## Wertebereich ##
xmin = 0
xmax = 50
xsteps = 1
x = np.arange(xmin,xmax,xsteps)
ymin = 0
ymax = 50
ysteps = 1
y = np.arange(ymin,ymax,ysteps)

#X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

## Klassendefinition ##
# hier wird eine Bohrloch-Klasse definiert    
class Bohrloch(object):
    # __init__ erzeugt das eigentliche Objekt mit seinen Parametern
    def __init__(self, xlage, ylage, tstart, q):
        self.xlage = xlage           # x-Lage der Bohrung
        self.ylage = ylage           # y-Lage der Bohrung
        self.tstart = tstart         # Start der Injektion/Produktion
        self.q = q                   # Fluidmenge

#==============================================================================
#                                   Drücke
#==============================================================================

    # getPressure erzeugt einen Array mit allen Werten für x,y im Zeitraum t    
    def getPressure(self, t): 
        if (t-self.tstart<0):        # Förderzeit muss in Förderzeitraum liegen
            print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
            return () 

        else:
            # erzeugen des Abstandsvektors
            self.r = np.sqrt((x-self.xlage)**2+(y-self.ylage)**2)
            # Druckformel nach Rudnicki (1986)
            self.P = (self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart))))
            # Druck wird direkt bei der Bohrung als "not a number" definiert
            self.P[self.xlage] = np.nan
            self.P[self.ylage] = np.nan
            # Umrechnung des Druckes in [MPa]
            self.z = self.P/1e6
            # return gibt die Druckwerte aus (und speichert sie zwischen)

            return self.z
```

The issue i have is that i get back an 1 dimensional array of `self.z`. The idea behind the code is the following:

I have an x- and and y-axis, e.g. with the ranges above. I try to get pressure values (depending from x,y) for each possible combination of these 1d-arrays, e.g. values for x,y = 1,1 ; 1,2 ; 1,3  and so on until 50 on each axis. If i test the dimension of my array self.z with `ndim`, i see that i only have covered one dimension. The desired output should be a two dimensional array with 50x50 entrys (or 49x49), or am i wrong? I'm really stuck to this problem, i think it should be simple to solve but i can't get it properly. Later on i want to plot a 3D Plot with these values, i know i have to use `np.meshgrid` for this issue. Do i have to use it also here?
I hope you guys get my idea and can help!

Comment: Print out to check if your array format for the desired variable is like this [[],[]..[]]

Comment: hi, thx for your advice...could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: In case the answer below works, mark it please as the solution, or tell us what is not working. Thanks

Comment: i forgot about it, thanks for the reminder! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation, the problem is in your definition of 'self.r'
You want a list of the distances r between (x,y) and (xlage,ylage) for all combinations of x and y, i.e. a matrix. However, you have a vector which contains r belonging to (x1,y1), (x2,y2),(x3,y3) ... , i.e. you are missing the combinations (x1,y2), ... etc.

The solution is

```
# put this into section 'Wertebereich'
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# and change the function to
def getPressure(self, t): 
    if (t-self.tstart<0):        # Förderzeit muss in Förderzeitraum liegen
        print "Startpunkt liegt außerhalb des Förderzeitraumes!"
        return () 

    else:
        # erzeugen des Abstandsvektors
        self.r = np.sqrt((xx-self.xlage)**2+(yy-self.ylage)**2)
        # Druckformel nach Rudnicki (1986)
        self.P = (self.q/(rhof*4*pi*kappa))*(expn(1,self.r**2/(4*c*(t-self.tstart))))
        # Druck wird direkt bei der Bohrung als "not a number" definiert
        self.P = np.where((xx==self.xlage) & (yy==self.ylage),self.P,NaN)
        # Umrechnung des Druckes in [MPa]
        self.z = self.P/1e6
        # return gibt die Druckwerte aus (und speichert sie zwischen)

        return self.z
```

I can't check the code right now but it should do the job.

You can then plot it by using xx,yy and the output z, as described [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i get it right, i just have to use np.meshgrid in my section Wertebereich/range of values? Your suggestion of using where also makes sense, i will test it asap.

Comment: Maybe you can even drop the 'np.where' part. I assume that the function 'expn' is divergent for r=0? So you get a NaN anyway? Maybe you think about to put xlage,ylage not on a node.